# How to convert ISBN-10 to ISBN-13 in Vim?

Tags: vimscript, macro

My file contains ISBN-10 and ISBN-13, e.g.:

```
isbn:0062316095, more text
isbn:1847922635, much more text
isbn:9780486406510, even more text
```

I want to convert every ISBN-10 to the according ISBN-13 ([rules](https://www.isbn-information.com/convert-isbn-10-to-isbn-13.html)). How can I do that in Vim?

Vim version is MacVim 8.0.525 (130).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this does what you want. I've made a function to do the conversion and a mapping that triggers it. Simply place your cursor on the ISBN-10 and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to replace it with its corresponding ISBN-13 number. (`<A-i>` is just a suggestion, and you can, of course, change it to whatever works best for you.)

```
nnoremap <A-i> ciw<C-r>=ISBN10ToISBN13('<C-r>"')<CR>

function! ISBN10ToISBN13(ISBN10)
   let ISBN13 = ''
   if (strlen(a:ISBN10) == 10)
      " Remove last number
      let ISBN13 = strpart(a:ISBN10, 0, 9)
      " Prepend 978
      let ISBN13 = '978'.ISBN13

      " Calculate the check digit
      let i = 1
      let total = 0
      for digit in split(ISBN13, '\zs')
         let total += str2nr(digit)*i
         if (i == 1)
            let i = 3
         else
            let i = 1
         endif
      endfor
      let check = (10 - (total % 10)) % 10

      " Append the check digit
      let ISBN13 .= check
      return ISBN13
   else
      " Return -1 if input digit is invalid.
      return -1
   endif
endfunction
```

And finally to replace ALL ISBN-10 in a file you can run a global command like the following:

```
:g/isbn:\d\{10}\>/ exe "normal!wwciw\<C-r>=ISBN10ToISBN13('\<C-r>\"')\<CR>"
```

- `:g` run a command on every line that matches a pattern.
- `/isbn:\d\{10}\>/` A pattern that matches only ISBN-10 numbers.
- `exe ...` Execute the following command (We need this so that we can use special characters like `<C-r>`)
- `normal!...` A normal command that is identical to the `<A-i>` mapping above.

See [`:help split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split%28%29), [`:help str2nr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#str2nr%28%29),  [`:help c_<C-R>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_%3CC-R%3E), and [`:help :global`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) for more info.

Comment: You are awesome.

Comment: You could also apply your function to a substitute command, something in the lines of: `:%s/isbn:\zs\d\{10\}\>/\=ISBN10ToISBN13(submatch(0))/g`. I think that would be slightly better than the global command, for instance because it would work for multiple isbn's on a single line.